# Python count transform and aggregate dates to month columns

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset where I am trying to breakdown and count the number of occurrences by month.  I would also need to transform the end result to add a column for each month/occurrence

```
Report_ID    Report_name    timestamp    
1            Profit         8/1/2018 06:10:40
2            Revenue        8/5/2018 09:25:45
1            Profit         8/29/2018 10:11:30
2            Revenue        9/1/2018  09:45:22
```

Output:

```
Report_ID   8/2018    9/2018
1           2         0 
2           1         1
```

Comment: Is your data in a `pandas` dataframe or some other format?

Comment: It would becoming in from a .xlsx file and then read into python via pd.read_excel()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.crosstab` with dt accessor using `strftime`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.Report_ID, df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%m/%Y'))\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename_axis([None], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Report_ID  08/2018  09/2018
0          1        2        0
1          2        1        1
```

Comment: @Scott, this works great!  Thank you so much!  one quick follow up, my dataset has life to date (12+ months of) data.  How would i limit the cross tab dataframe to the last 3 months?

Comment: Create a new dataframe with only the last three months of data, and then use the same command.